# How does one interpret the naive t-structure on constructible sheaves as a t-structure on D-modules?

Tags: t-structure, d-modules, perverse-sheaves, ag.algebraic-geometry

By the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, there is an equivalence between

(1) 
    $\mathcal{D}\operatorname{-mod}(X)$
, the (derived) category of holonomic D-modules on a complex variety X, and

(2) 
    $D^b_c(X)$
, the (derived) category of constructible sheaves  on X.

There is a "naive" t-structure we can put on both categories.  In 
    $\mathcal{D}\operatorname{-mod}(X)$
, we can look at a t-structure whose heart 
    $\mathcal{D}\operatorname{-mod}^\heartsuit$
 is a complex (of D-modules) concentrated in degree 0.  In 
    $D^b_c(X)$
, we can look at the naive t-structure whose heart 
    $D^{b \heartsuit}_c$
 is a complex (of constructible sheaves) concentrated in degree 0.

It's known that if we transfer the naive t-structure on 
    $\mathcal{D}\operatorname{-mod}(X)$
 to 
    $D^b_c(X)$
 (using the equivalence above), 
    $\mathcal{D}\operatorname{-mod}^\heartsuit$
 is identified with "perverse sheaves" on X.

My question is:

> If we map 
>       $D^{b\heartsuit}_c$
>    to the category of D-modules using the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, what subcategory of 
>       $\mathcal{D}\operatorname{-mod}$
>    do we get?  Does this have a well-known name?
>
> More generally, is there some geometric/nice description of what the naive t-structure on 
>       $D^b_c$
>    becomes on 
>       $\mathcal{D}{\operatorname{-mod}}$
>   ?

Comment: There must be a kind of tautological answer along the lines of: consider objects in the derived category of D-modules such that *-restriction to a subvariety lies in such and such degrees and the !-restriction to a subvariety lies in such and such degrees. (By tautological I mean for instance that it would apply to any perversity). Are you looking for something more non-trivial?

Comment: I guess the naive t-structure viewed from the vantage of D-modules will be as perverse as the perverse t-structure for sheaves. In other words, I doubt there's a simple answer. You can describe it inductively by applying Theorem 1.4.10 of BBD (the tautological answer in the above sense).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The t-structure is described in 
[this paper of Kashiwara](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0302086).
  It looks essentially like Donu and t3suji suggest in their comments: defined by conditions that look like middle-perversity support conditions.